# Perl execute command, capture and display output

Tags: perl, background-process

I need to execute a command from my Perl script, which is going to take a while (1-2 hours). I want to be able to see the output of the command, so that my script can check everything went OK, but as it takes such a long time, I'd like the user to see the commands output while it runs, too.

What I've tried:

- `backticks` - Can only get output when command is finished
- `system` - Can only get output when command is finished
- `open` - Almost perfect - but the commands output is buffered, meaning users don't see an update for a long time. Internet is full of suggestions to set `$| = 1` but apparently this only affects input buffering and doesn't work
- Piping to `tee` - Similar results to `open` - 'tee' only seems to print later
- Re-directing output and Using `Proc::Background` and `File::Tail` - Almost perfect again, but can't think of an elegant way to stop the print loop

Would love to have a suggestion!

---

Edit: I've accepted Barmars answer. I believe it works because Expect.pm uses a pseudo-terminal. Just to others looking at this question in future, this is how I've implemented it:

```
my $process = Expect->spawn($command, @params) or die "Cannot spawn $command: $!\n";

while ($process->expect(undef))
{
  print $process->before();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/214005/1331451

Comment: Setting autoflush to a true value disables buffering for the currently `select`ed file handle. How is that different from what you are asking for?

Comment: TLP, as I said I tried that, and it didn't seem to work. Upon researching it, I read that autoflush only affects input buffering.

Comment: The phrase `it doesn't work` and all its variations is next to useless without elaboration. And no, it is *output* buffering. There is no input buffering.

Comment: simbabque: I've seen that, thanks - but that solution... well, I'd rather just re-write my script in C than do that. TLP: I'm not sure what you don't understand. I'll try again: "Setting $| = 1, or fileHandle->autoflush(1); both result in the same behaviour as if they had not been set".

Comment: It sounds like the command you are executing does not `fflush()` its output unless it detects a terminal on `stdout`. Others with similar problems might be able to force the command into interactive mode somehow. `IPC::Run` may also do what you want, but in this case it sounds like the built-in pattern matching of `Expect` is a good fit for your script.

Comment: @TLP, I would add more than one up to that comment if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Expect.pm` should disable output buffering in the command.

Comment: Seems to work beautifully and has an elegant implementation. Thanks!