# How to launch interactive commands from Perl while allowing Perl to parse the command output

Tags: linux, perl, pipe, background-process

### The Question

How do I change a Perl script to allow for both unattended and
interactive execution of the child process, such that in the
interactive scenario, the user interacts with the GDB just like they
would if the Perl script was not also parsing the output? And showing
prompts and keyboard presses as the user presses them, not after they
press the Enter key.

### Details

I have a Perl script that launches child processes and reads the
output, taking various actions on the output, but always just printing
the output to standard output. Normally, the child process is an
unattended process that does not require user input (i.e., does not
read from standard input). However, sometimes that child process needs
to be changed to run GDB, and GDB *does* need to both prompt the user
with a prompt of "(gdb) " (*without* printing a newline character),
read the users input (which is then terminated by the user pressing
the Enter key), process the users command, and emit the resulting
output (which may be from its application under GDB control, or from
GDB itself). However, the Perl script as currently written reads the
GDB prompt but does not print out that prompt immediately, and also
does not immediately print out each character of the users input as
they type each character (and including any usage of backspace, arrow
key stroke handling, etc.), but prints out both the gdb prompt and the
users input all at once *after* the user finally presses the Enter
key.  Thus, the user has to literally type as if they were
blind-folded, and cannot immediately see what they have typed *until*
the Perl script completes the reading of the entire line of output,
and then prints out the entire input line. Forcing the user to type
blind-folded **is** the problem.

### Constraints

1. Changing anything in the "real child process" is not an option, but only the Perl script or any intervening "helper scripts" or utilities (if needed) that the Perl script may choose to use (i.e., temporarily generate via here-documents or similar mechanism.).
2. Must not require any version of Perl greater than v5.14.2.
3. Changing the Perl script to read character output one character at a time and emitting it, *unless* it is provably as performant as reading entire lines of output (the size of the output of the real-world scenarios is voluminous).
4. Use of heavy-weight tools that are not built into versions of Linux including very old out of date versions of Linux such as RHEL6. This negates the use of Expect, too. It *might* also negate use of Expect.pm as indicated in [Perl execute command, capture and display output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12244863/257924) but am unsure as that might require installation of additional Perl packages, with its attendent risks.
5. Changing the use of the tools that invoke gdb to instead attach to an existing child process after it is running. In some scenarios, the gdb needs to be involved prior to `::main()` in the application to be debugged.

### Viable possibilities

1. Change the Perl script to allow the standard input to be interacted with via redirection using two pipes or something similar. I am unsure how to go about that, in Perl.
2. Change the Perl script to launch a intermediate script as a child process that does the redirection, and then the Perl script reads from the separate pipe. Similar to the above: I'm unsure how to code that.

### The Minimal Complete Verifiable Example (MCVE)

The Bash script below writes out all scripts and launches them. You
can execute this inside /tmp on Linux. I've not tested this script on
any other platform than Linux, so do not expect it to work without
modifications.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Dump out a perl_script script:
#
#   The perl_script below runs gdb directly on the sleep command, but
#   in the real-world scenario, instead of sleep, there would be a
#   complex script that calls other scripts that finally may or may
#   not invoke gdb.
#
cat > perl_script <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

# Just for the question, just call gdb directly, but in real-world
# practice, this command would be some other script that eventually
# executes gdb as a child process:
my $shell_command="gdb sleep 999999";

print "perl_script: Executing $shell_command in a pipe ...\n";

my $error_code;  # Leave $error_code undefined here.
open(SUBSHELL_FP, "$shell_command |") || do {
  $error_code = -1;
};
# Avoid reading from a pipe that immediately failed, as indicated by undefined $error_code:
if (!defined($error_code)) {
  while(<SUBSHELL_FP>) {
    print; # print output to the user

    # Not shown here is the parsing of the output of <SUBSHELL_FP> for
    # various strings and taking action upon them that is unrelated to
    # the gdb execution.

    # It is this reading of <SUBSHELL_FP> that "hides" the "(gdb)"
    # prompt and also the keypress output from the user that is typing
    # into the gdb prompt, and only emits it upon the _subsequent_
    # call to print above in the next loop iteration.

  }
  close(SUBSHELL_FP);
  $error_code = $?;
}
print "End of run with error code $error_code\n";
EOF

# Make the perl_script executable:
chmod a+x perl_script

# Execute the perl_script:
#
#   While this perl_script is running, the user can type "info br"
#   (and press the Enter key) to see some output (just to force gdb to
#   emit an answer which is that there are no breakpoints).  But,
#   typing letters into the xterm is NOT displayed, and neither is the
#   "(gdb)" prompt, at least at first. Just as soon as the user
#   presses the Enter key, the Perl script above prints the prompt and
#   the users input (see "print output to the user" above).
#
#   Then the user can press CTRL+d to exit the gdb process, which will
#   then return to the "read" below.
#
./perl_script

# Here, the user has executed gdb and thus exited the
# perl_script. Indicate that the script has finished:
echo Hit enter to continue
# shellcheck disable=SC2034
read -r dont_care
```

Comment: Why are you including the bootstrapping code to _create_ the perl script? Anyway, take a look at [`IPC::Open3`](https://perldoc.perl.org/IPC::Open3)

Comment: perl 5.14 and RHEL6 are a dozen years old. At some point it's better to bite the bullet and upgrade instead of trying to limp on with long obsolete and unsupported software (though RHEL has another year of ELS for paying customers left before it's completely done with)

Comment: I'd look into using gdb's [MI interface](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/GDB_002fMI.html#GDB_002fMI) assuming the ancient version you're probably using supports it. Or tcl/expect instead of perl. This is exactly the sort of thing expect is designed for.

Comment: *"gdb sleep 999999"* : I don't think you can pass arguments to sleep like that. According to the [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) you should be using `--args` to pass arguments to the inferior. But I think `gdb sleep` will be enough for this example, right?

Comment: There are nice ways to do it, but not within the constraints of "only use stuff that's already installed on systems from 2011". You want IO::Pty::Easy and/or IO::Pty::HalfDuplex.

Comment: All criticisms I have read so far in the above comments appear to me to be spot-on and valid.  Unfortunately, there are factors beyond my control that thwart my every move here. See also my comments on the [Expect.pm related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76708670/257924) 
 below also.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I change a Perl script to allow for both unattended and interactive execution of the child process, such that in the interactive scenario, the user interacts with the GDB just like they would if the Perl script was not also parsing the output?

Good question. Currently I could not find the solution without using `Expect`, but I am investigating this further. Here are my preliminary findings:

As long as you are not trying to read the output of the child process it works fine. The user input from STDIN is shown in real time (as required, and you do not have to press enter to see it) in the terminal:

```
use v5.38;
use experimental 'class';

{
    my $self = Main->new();
    $self->start_process();
    $self->cleanup();
}

class Main;
field $_child_pid;

method cleanup() {
    say "Parent: waiting for child..";
    waitpid($_child_pid, 0);
}

method start_process() { # See: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc
    if ($_child_pid = fork()) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        die "cannot fork: $!" unless defined $_child_pid;
        # This is the child process
        exec "gdb", "sleep";
        exit 0;
    }
}
```

However, if I try to read the child STDOUT (as you mentioned in your question that you would do), the user input is not shown until the user presses ENTER in the terminal (so unfortunately, the below script does not work as required):

```
use v5.38;
use experimental 'class';

use IO::Select;
{
    my $self = Main->new();
    $self->start_process();
    $self->select_loop();
    $self->cleanup();
}

class Main;
field $_child_pid;
field $_child_rdr;

method cleanup() {
    say "Parent: waiting for child..";
    waitpid($_child_pid, 0);
}

method select_loop() {
    my $timeout = 10;
    my $sel = IO::Select->new( $_child_rdr );
    while (1) {
        local $! = 0; # Clear ERRNO such that we can differentiate between timeout and other errors
        my @ready = $sel->can_read( $timeout );
        if (!@ready) {
            if ($!) {
                die "Select() failed with error: $!";
            }
            else {
                die "Select() timed out";
            }
        }
        my $handle = $ready[0];
        my $result = <$handle>;
        if (!defined $result) {
            last;  #EOF
        }
        print ":: ", $result;
    }
}

method start_process() { # See: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc
    pipe($_child_rdr,  my $parent_wtr);
    $parent_wtr->autoflush(1);
    if ($_child_pid = fork()) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        die "cannot fork: $!" unless defined $_child_pid;
        # This is the child process
        close $_child_rdr;
        open (STDOUT, ">&", $parent_wtr) or die $!;
        open (STDERR, ">&", $parent_wtr) or die $!;
        exec "gdb", "sleep";
        exit 0;
    }
}
```

I am not sure why this simple change of trying to read from the child's STDOUT changes the behavior of the terminal and prevents the STDIN from being echoed in real time (only echoed after the user presses enter).

**Update**:

Using [`Expect`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect) seems to work though, but you need to look for the "(gdb)" prompt and then call `interact()`:

```
use v5.38;
use experimental 'class';
use Expect;
{
    my $self = Main->new();
    $self->start_process();
    $self->expect_loop();
    $self->cleanup();
}

class Main;
field $_exp;

method cleanup() {
    say "Parent: cleaning up..";
    $_exp->hard_close();
}

method expect_loop() {
    my $timeout = 20;
    while (1) {
        my ( $matched_pattern_position, $error, $successfully_matching_string, $before_match, $after_match)
            = $_exp->expect($timeout, '-re', '\\(gdb\\) ');
        if (defined $error) {
            if ($error eq '1:TIMEOUT' ) {
                say "expect: timeout";
            }
            elsif ($error eq '2:EOF') {
                say "expect: child EOF";
            }
            else {
                say "expect: error";
            }
            last;
        }
        $_exp->interact();
    }
}

method start_process() {
    my $cmd='gdb';
    my @param = qw(sleep);
    $_exp = Expect->new();
    $_exp->spawn($cmd, @param) or die "Cannot spawn $cmd: $!\n";
}
```

You mentioned in your question that you could not use `Expect`, can you clarify why not?

Comment: In the OP, I said "It _might_ also negate use of Expect.pm..." which is not the same thing as saying that it definitely would negate the use of that Perl Expect.pm package. I wish to avoid doing an upgrade of Perl packages for that old Perl version. I also don't know what non-Perl Linux packages that Perl package depends upon, and I didn't want to open up a can of worms in terms of dependency management.  I will experiment with your answer and see how difficult it would be to make it work. Thank you!

Comment: I reconfirmed my suspicion that Expect.pm is a CPAN provided package, and not built into the base Perl installation I am having to use at the moment.  So, this answer _would_, IMO, likely be a viable answer had Expect.pm been built into the Perl installation, which it is not in my case, and I am not going to go down that path of installing it at this juncture until I have exhausted all other alternatives.